# npm run build command deletes all files and folders in next.js

Tags: next.js

I installed the next.js app by running **npx create-next-app@latest**.

This is my next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    distDir: "./"
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }
}
```

I ran **npm run build** command and all the files folders got deleted. Is there a way to restore the files ? What's the reason for deletion of all the files. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: This is happening because of distDir: "./" configuaration.